# How to insert a conditional_variable object into a Vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

conditional_variable is not CopyConstructible, MoveConstructible, CopyAssignable, MoveAssignable.

Can we call like this

```
vector<conditional_variable> cond;

conditional_variable c1;
conditional_variable c2;
cond.push_back(c1);
cond.push_back(c2);
```

What is the right way to proceed in these scenarios

Comment: You could try `vector<unique_ptr<conditional_variable>>`

Comment: I'm wondering why one would need a `vector` of `condition_variable` to begin with. To solve what problem?

Comment: maybe `std::vector::emplace_back` does the trick?

Comment: @Julian not for vectors, since it may reallocate.

Comment: @T.C. yes, unfortunately you are right... :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can create a vector of something that can be default constructed but can't be copied or moved by using the constructor taking a size argument:

```
std::vector<std::condition_variable> cv_vec(20);
```

Such a vector cannot be grown, but may be shrunk with `pop_back()` or `clear()` (but not `erase()` or `resize()`).

Alternatively, since everything can be solved with an extra level of indirection, you can have a vector of `std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable>` instead.

Now, why on earth someone would want to do this for a synchronization primitive like `condition_variable`, I have no idea...

Comment: Thanks T.C for your reply. I dont want to use conditional_variable vector as such. The question was basically to find a way to use classes without copy constructors in vectors.
So, in this kind of scenario  I will go with the std::unique_ptr<> way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem ist, that `std::vector` allocates an array somewhere in memory, and needs to move that array to another location, if the vector is grown later. So even this code fails to compile:

```
std::vector<std::condition_variable> cvvector;
cvvector.emplace_back();
```

The solution is to use the more versatile container `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`. A `std::deque` never moves the actual storage allocated for its objects. `std::deque` nonetheless has constant access time for element reference via the `[]` operator:

```
std::deque<std::condition_variable> cvvector;
cvvector.emplace_back();
cvvector.emplace_back();
std::condition_variable& cv = cvvector[1];
```

I call the container still `cvvector`: As long, as you don't use `cvvector::emplace_front()` or `cvvector::pop_front()`, it behaves like a vector, not like a queue.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't,
I would suggest you to use a `vector<unique_ptr<conditional_variable>>`. Then you can allocate a new `conditional_variable` and add it to your vector

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `std::condition_variable` into a `std::vector<A_with_cv>`, by having the vector hold objects `A_with_cv`, that have copy constuctor and copy assignment operator that do not copy the member `std::condition_variable`.

Here's an example:

```cpp
// compile with: c++ -std=c++14 -o go main.cpp -pthread

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    A()                  {}
    A(int d) : data_{d}  {}

    int  data()          const { return data_; }
    void set_data(int d)       { data_ = d;    }
private:
    int data_{0};
};

class A_with_cv : public A {
public:
    A_with_cv(int d = 0) : A{d}
    {}

    A_with_cv(const A_with_cv &a) : A{static_cast<const A&>(a)} // don't copy cv_ !
    {}

    A_with_cv &operator=(const A_with_cv &other)
    {
        static_cast<A&>(*this) = static_cast<const A&>(other); // don't copy cv_ !
    }

    std::condition_variable       &cv()       { return cv_; };
    const std::condition_variable &cv() const { return cv_; };
private:
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};


struct Printer {
public:
    Printer(std::vector<A_with_cv> &vec) {
        initiate_print(vec);
    }

    void initiate_print(std::vector<A_with_cv> &vec) {
        for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ) {
            auto &val_ref = *it;

            ++it; // increment
            if (it != vec.end()) {
                auto &next_ref = *it;
                th_vec_.push_back(std::thread(
                                              [&]() {
                                                  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut_);
                                                  val_ref.cv().wait(lk);
                                                  std::cout << val_ref.data() << std::endl;
                                                  lk.unlock();
                                                  next_ref.cv().notify_one(); // notify next
                                              }));
            } else {
                th_vec_.push_back(std::thread(
                                              [&]() {
                                                  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut_);
                                                  val_ref.cv().wait(lk);
                                                  std::cout << val_ref.data() << std::endl;
                                              }));
            }
        }
    }

    void wait_for_thread_completion() {
        for (auto &th : th_vec_) {
            th.join();
        }
    }
private:
    std::mutex mut_;
    std::vector<std::thread> th_vec_;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<A_with_cv> vec;
    vec.push_back(A_with_cv(1));
    vec.push_back(A_with_cv(2));
    vec.push_back(A_with_cv(3));

    Printer printer(vec);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{500});
    vec[0].cv().notify_one();

    printer.wait_for_thread_completion();
}
```

But be very careful when using a vector for this. A vector can reallocate elements, and you might think you're notifying a condition_variable, while actually it does no longer exist (for example because you've done some push_backs in the mean time, and the iterators and references to vector elements, have been invalidated)!
So for this, rather prefer a container that does not reallocate/invalidate elements such as `std::list` (or - provided you only add elements at the front or back: `std::deque`) etc. since that is safer!

When using such containers, that do not reallocate/invalidate elements, be sure to use emplace. Example:

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::condition_variable> deq;
    //deq.push_back(std::condition_variable());                 // does not work
    deq.emplace_back();

    std::list<std::condition_variable> li;
    //li.push_back(std::condition_variable());                  // does not work
    li.emplace_back();

    std::map<int, std::condition_variable> ma;
    //ma.insert( std::make_pair(1, std::condition_variable())); // does not work
    //ma.emplace(std::make_pair(1, std::condition_variable())); // does not work
    ma.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple(1),
               std::forward_as_tuple());

    return 0;
}
```